# Chrome extension, manifest v3, how to use window.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am interested to port barbushin's most excellent JavaScript Errors Notifier back into the Chrome Store.  To do so, it must be converted from manifest v2 to manifest v3. In V2, the JavaScript to add event listeners for errors runs fine. However, I'm unable to get the same code to run in manifest v3.

I am trying here, where I've made a conversion effort which installs without errors https://github.com/coinzdude/javascript-errors-notifier/tree/manifest-v3

Here is what I have tried.  To load the page level JavaScript, I am using in the manifest

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox"
  },

    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "matches": ["file://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["code-to-inject.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "code-to-inject.js",
```

With the code for the event listeners in code-to-inject.js like below

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
          console.log('cti event listener error')
this.alert('cti error event')
  if (e.filename) {
    document.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('ErrorToExtension', {
        detail: {
          stack: e.error ? e.error.stack : null,
          url: e.filename,
          line: e.lineno,
          col: e.colno,
          text: e.message,
        },
      }),
    )
  }
})
```

But these don't seem to work, as no error events are caught with an alert.  I'm not getting an JS alerts or console log messages.

Any ideas? I'm guessing that I'm missing something in the manifest, or that my code-to-inject.js while running, is not actually in the page scope.

Comment: This is probably a context problem, your content script listener will only be triggered by events that happen in that context not the context of the page/frame that it was injected in.

Comment: Also, what is `"world": "MAIN"` supposed to do ? It is not mentioned in either the [webExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) or the [documentation for Chrome extensions manifest V2](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)

Comment: I am looking to use a feature that was added as of 102+ https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/ RegisteredContentScript.world , and the code does run, at least the alerts and console logs outside of event listeners does run. I am struggling to find where I found this very recent add to the manifest structure. I will keep looking.   I may also try then to load the script into the 'main world' from the service worker like so https://docs.plasmo.com/framework/content-scripts

Comment: I see, I don't think you can specify the `world` directly in the manifest, it is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/). You can probably only set that when you use `chrome.scripting.executeScript(...)`. A good test to do is to just add `throw new Error('testing...')` to your content script, if that triggers the listener, it means the listener works as expected but for some reason only in the content script's context.

Comment: 1) "world": "MAIN" in manifest.json is implemented only in Chrome 111. In earlier Chrome you need to use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts in the background script. 2) Remove `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I could not find the web page again noting the Chrome 111 addition of "world": "MAIN" support added in manifest.json, but yes, that is what I'm trying and it loads without error.  Thanks for noting I can remove the file from web_accessible_resources.

Comment: I think I'm still off the mark because I tried this same both with Chrome 112, and while there are no errors, the event listener for 'error' does not appear to be registered and is not called when there is a JS error in the page.

Comment: I've tried also loading the script from background.js with  ```chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([
  {
    id: '0',
    matches: ['file://*/*', 'http://*/*', 'https://*/*'],
    js: ['code-to-inject.js'],
    world: 'MAIN',
    runAt: 'document_start',
  },
])
``` but it still does not seem to register

Comment: 1) Your code from the github repo works for me, so there's nothing catastrophically wrong in it. Try a new browser profile or uninstall the extension and install it again. 2) Don't forget to wrap the entire contents of code-to-inject.js inside IIFE `(()=> { ... })()` otherwise your code will fail on pages with the same globals.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the IIFE. I checked that in. The extension also installs for me without error, but it does not call the registered event listener from `  window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {`  I made a simple test JS error page here https://github.com/coinzdude/javascript-errors-notifier/blob/manifest-v3/jserror.html which is handled by the Manifest V2 extension, but is missed by the V3 version

Comment: @Titus Yes, great idea. Throwing an error at the end of the 'code-to-inject.js' does indeed get caught by the defined error listener inside of that file, within that scope. I just need to find out why it's not running at the page scope.

Comment: At least with Chrome 112, I am actually getting into the background worker when an error is thrown.  That background worker is erroring with trying to update the DOM, so that makes sense that I need to figure out how to send a message from the background worker back into the frontend.  The legacy manifest v2 code is as ``` var div = document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: However, with chrome 110, I cannot get the error handler registered.  I am trying this in background.js  `chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([
 {
  id: '0',
  matches: ['file://*/*', 'http://*/*', 'https://*/*'],
  js: ['code-to-inject.js'],
  world: 'MAIN',
  runAt: 'document_start',
 },
]);`

Comment: Like I said, your code **works** for me, meaning it really intercepts the errors as it should. Try removing all `alert` and instead use `console.log` or proper debugging in devtools.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this working well.

top of background.js file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'loading') {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id, allFrames: true },
      files: ['code-to-inject.js'],
    })
  }
})
```

with manifest like this

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["content.js", "document_start.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "matches": ["file://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["code-to-inject.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

...

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "img/error_64.png",
        "img/error_38.png",
        "img/error_19.png",
        "popup.html",
        "options.html",
        "code-to-inject.js"
      ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "webRequest", "storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"]
```